# Parse Server running with postgres Parse error: error: column "_rperm" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, parse-server

I have setup the parse server to connect in postgres database. 
databaseURI: 'postgres://postgres:mypassoword@localhost:5432/fantasy'. After that I have started the server with: nodejs index.js.

The service have started fine, however when I try to make a call to my API, I am getting the follow error in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log

> postgres@fantasy ERROR:  column "_rperm" does not exist at character
>   30 2019-10-01 21:44:47.468 -03 [10895] postgres@fantasy STATEMENT: 
>   SELECT * FROM "jogos" WHERE ("_rperm" IS NULL OR "_rperm" &&
>   ARRAY['*','*'])  LIMIT 100

The logs in Parse server (version: ) are:

> error: Parse error: error: column "_rperm" does not exist
>   {"code":1,"stack":"Error: error: column \"_rperm\" does not exist\n
>   at
>   /root/parse-server-example/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Controllers/DatabaseController.js:1179:21\n
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"}

I am using the current version of parse server version 3.9.0.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps show us the definition / description of the table in question (```\d "jogos"``` inside ```psql```). Perhaps your quoted identifiers are the problem. Ideally, you would never use such (exception for aliases if needed), because there is no real payoff.

Comment: Thks @lslingre I'll try it!

Comment: Is it a brand new database that you are connecting your Parse Server to? Are you able to create new objects to the class jogos?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo It's a new database with just a few record inserted directly in pgadmin. I haven't tried create new objects thought the POST method yet. But when i have started the parse service I notice several tables of parse server were created in my schema, therefore seems like I am missing some crucial details in the setup process. If I could not find out soon may I'll try to change to mongodb. I appreciate your help. If you have a good link that show how to insert new an object thought POST will be useful.

Comment: That's probably the reason of your error. Inserting data directly to the db can make Parse Server to fail. You can try to insert the data either via [Parse Dashboard](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard) or using the API. It would be something like this: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#creating-objects

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Thks! I will try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the tips of @DaviMacêdo I was able to solve my problem by creating the objects/tables directly through the Parse Dashboard.

First I have to create self sign certificates:

```
$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout key.pem -out csr.pem
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out server.crt
```

Then I created a node script to initialize both the parse server and parse dashboard. file: dashboard.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var app = express();
var port = 1337;

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt', 'utf8'),
};

var parse = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: 'postgres://postgres:dbpassword@localhost:5432/fantasy',
    appId: 'fantasy',
    masterKey: 'MyPa$$word',
    serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse' 
});

var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
    "apps": [{
        "serverURL": "https://myserver:1337/parse",
        "appId": "fantasy",
        "masterKey": "MyPa$$word",
        "appName": "Fantasy"
    }],
    "users": [{
        "user": "admin",
        "pass": "MyPa$$word"
    }]
});

app.use('/parse', parse);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);

var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log("server listening on port " + port);
});
```

To start parse server and parse dashboard:

> $ node dashboard.js &